# LAPACK orthonormalization function

Tags: linear-algebra, lapack

Is there ready routine in lapack to perform orthonormalization, for example Gram-Schmidt or some variation of QR method?

if not, what is the advised approach to perform orthonormalization using lapack?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is!  Look at:

```
sgeqrf (single precision real)
dgeqrf (double precision real)
cgeqrf (single precision complex)
zgeqrf (double precision complex)
```

In general, for LAPACK documentation, consult [netlib](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/).

Answer (score 2):

Here direct links to the documentation:

- [SGEQRF](http://apfel.mathematik.uni-ulm.de/~lehn/lapack-3.3.1/SRC/sgeqrf.html)
- [DGEQRF](http://apfel.mathematik.uni-ulm.de/~lehn/lapack-3.3.1/SRC/dgeqrf.html)
- [CGEQRF](http://apfel.mathematik.uni-ulm.de/~lehn/lapack-3.3.1/SRC/cgeqrf.html)
- [ZGEQRF](http://apfel.mathematik.uni-ulm.de/~lehn/lapack-3.3.1/SRC/zgeqrf.html)