# Lapack Orthonormalization Function for Rectangular Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, lapack, cusolver, qr-decomposition

I was wondering if there was a function in Lapack for orthonormalizing the columns of a very tall and skinny matrix. [A similar previous question asked this question, presumably in the context of a square matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515103/lapack-orthonormalization-function). My setting is as follows: I have an M by N matrix A that I am trying to orthonormalize the columns of.

So, my first thought was to do a qr decomposition. The functions for doing a qr decomposition in Lapack seem to be dgeqrf and dormqr. Great. However, my problem is as follows: my matrix A is so tall, that I don't want to actually compute all of Q, because it is M by M. In fact, I can't afford to instantiate an M by M matrix at all during any of my computation (it would not fit in memory). I would rather compute just the matrix that [wikipedia calls Q1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition#Rectangular_matrix). However, I can't seem to find a way to make this work.

The weird thing is, that I think it is possible. Numpy, in particular, has a function [numpy.linalg.qr](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.10.0/numpy/linalg/linalg.py#L617-L826) that appears to do just this. However, even after reading their source code, I can't figure out how they are using lapack calls to get this to work.

Do folks have ideas? I would strongly prefer this to only use lapack functions because I am hoping to port this code to CuSOLVE, which has implemented several lapack functions (including dgeqrf and dormqr) for the GPU.

Answer (score 0):

You want the "thin" or "economy size" version of QR. In matlab, you can do this with:

```
[Q,R] = qr(A,0);
```

I haven't used Lapack directly, but I would imagine there's a corresponding call there. It appears that you can do this in python with:

```
numpy.linalg.qr(a, mode='reduced')
```